# how to get first 100 prime numbers in python with no duplicate value?

Tags: python

I am trying to get first 100 prime numbers using python, for that I have created a function and given one parameter to that function, I have tried below code,

```
# WAP to fund first 100 prime numbers
def getprimes(x):
primes = []

for a in range(1,10000):
    for b in range(2,a):
        if(a%b==0):
            break
        else:
            primes.append(a)
        if len(primes) == x:
            return primes

getprimes(100)  #function call
```

## here I am getting first 100 prime numbers but with duplicate value, I want unique values, how can I do that?

Comment: Reduce your testset, from 10000 to e.g. 10. Further, learn how to step through your code with a debugger. You could then immediately determine when your code doesn't do what you'd expect it to do.

Comment: For *every combination of a and b* you are adding `a` to `primes` unless `b` divides `a`. That's not what you want to do.

Comment: E.g. `8` is not a prime, but when `b` is `3` `if(a%b==0)` is false, and so you execute `primes.append()`. Try to think of ways to alter the code to only record `a` as a prime if **all** values for `b` can't divide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
def getprimes(x):
    primes = []

    for a in range(1,10000):
        isPrime = True
        for b in range(2,a):
            if(a%b==0):
                isPrime = False
        if isPrime:
            primes.append(a)

        if len(primes) == x:
            return primes

print(getprimes(100))
```

I think the problem was you were recording a prime every time you found a valid factor instead of just one for each prime.

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Thanks for the help with the commenting @wwii - I was struggling as no matter what I did with the wysiwyg editor it would push either the first or last line of code out of the code block.

Comment: just a little modification required here, the program says 1 is a prime number and it is not, so I just made the change in condition here, if(isPrime and a!=1).